# Error when I render to RTX

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

I have a technical question for you.

The company in which I work has invested in better equipment. It is RTX 2080Ti and Ryzen 7 2700x.

I read that RTX is not currently supported by the program and you have to download the beta version or copy the files to the lib folder. I tested both ways and the render actually starts.
However, after some time everything starts to shouting and the tiles start to go crazy and become transparent. In the meantime I get an error: "CUDA Error: Illegal address in cuCtxSynchronize(),line 1151". Sometimes the numbers are different, e.g. 1372.
Beta version 2.79 and 2.80 can switch off for unknown reasons. The problem does not occur only when rendering on the processor.
I have the latest drivers for my graphics card and Cuda 10 installed.
Is there any way to render stable on 2.79b or any other version?

If something is not understandable, I'm sorry, the whole thing was translated in the Translator.

Comment: First question: Windows or Linux? And which version.

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot to add. The system is Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: The latest experimental 2.79 version, in combination with Geforce driver 430.39 appears to give a major performance improvement in rendering with an RTX card!

Answer (score 2):

I am rendering with multiple RTX2080ti GPU's in a windows 7 pro system and I am getting very good and stable results.
What I did was the following;

1. Download the latest experimental 2.79 version that supports RTX.
2. Replace the complete content of the C:\program files\blender foundation\blender 
   folder with the experimental 2.79 version. This will force windows to treat the 
   experimental version to run as an installed application, much better results!
3. Do not use the latest Geforce driver but find and install version 417.35

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I'll test it!